# Cloud Fusion Pipeline works well in Preview mode but throws error in Deployment mode

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have the below pipeline which ingests news data from RSS Feeds. Pipeline is contructed using HTTPPoller, XMLMultiParser Transorm, Javascript and MongoDB Sink. The pipeline works well in Preview mode but throws "bucket not found" error in Deployment mode

[RSS Ingest Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Stey.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJMzv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Data Fusion (CDF) creates a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket with the name format similar to the one mentioned in the error message in your GCP project when you create a CDF instance. Judging by the error message, its possible that the GCS bucket may have been deleted. Try to deploy the same pipeline in a new CDF instance (with the bucket present this time) and it should not raise the same exception.

This bucket is used as a Hadoop Compatible File System (HCFS) which is required to run pipelines on Dataproc